# coudn't install Mcafee antivirus software :

Tags: software-installation, antivirus

I tried to install the Mcafee antivirus software on my Ubuntu system 12.04.1 LTS. But I get this error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable libicu42
```

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://www.mcafee.com/de/products/virusscan-enterprise-for-linux.aspx) *MFErt.i686.deb*, and then install it with either of these two methods:

**GUI:**

Double-click on the `.deb` file, and then select to install it in the Ubuntu Software Center window which comes up.

[Documentation](http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_and_Uninstall_the_McAfee_Clients_on_Linux).

**Terminal:**

Open Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

`cd` to the location you downloaded it to (most likely the `Downloads` folder):

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

Then install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i MFErt.i686.deb
```

If there are any other dependency problems then install the additional dependencies afterwards with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```